# Laravel 5: How to validate querystring?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.

I have a situation where my url is http://example.com/gallery/delete/10

Where 10 is the  id (primary key) of the gallery table.

I want to validate that the gallery id 10 belongs to the logged in user and if so i will delete it. So I am using the following code

```
$deleted = Gallery::where('id', $Request->id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->delete();
```

Now, the *$deleted* variable holds the value 0 if the deletion isnt successful and 1 if the deletion was successful.

How do I make laravel show an error message in blade template if the deletion wasnt successful?

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```php
return view('your view')->(['flag' => $delete])
```

In blade:

```
@if(isset($flag) && $flag == 0)
    <div class='alert alert-warninig'>delete failure </div>
@endif

@if(isset($flag) && $flag == 1)
    <div class='alert alert-success'>delete successful</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there anyway i can use blade's default error variable $errors to show this error?